# How to deselect all selected rows in a DataGridView control?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I'd like to deselect all selected rows in a `DataGridView` control when the user clicks on a blank (non-row) part of the control.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

To deselect all rows and cells in a `DataGridView`, you can **use the [`ClearSelection` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxdf3ekh.aspx)**:

```
myDataGridView.ClearSelection()
```

If you don't want even the first row/cell to appear selected, you can **set the [`CurrentCell` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx) to `Nothing`/`null`**, which will temporarily hide the focus rectangle until the control receives focus again:

```
myDataGridView.CurrentCell = Nothing
```

To determine when the user has clicked on a blank part of the `DataGridView`, you're going to have to **handle its `MouseUp` event. In that event, you can [`HitTest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest.aspx) the click location and watch for this to indicate [`HitTestInfo.Nowhere`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.hittestinfo.nowhere.aspx)**. For example:

```
Private Sub myDataGridView_MouseUp(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    ''# See if the left mouse button was clicked
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        ''# Check the HitTest information for this click location
        If myDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y) = DataGridView.HitTestInfo.Nowhere Then
            myDataGridView.ClearSelection()
            myDataGridView.CurrentCell = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course, you could also subclass the existing `DataGridView` control to combine all of this functionality into a single custom control. You'll need to override its [`OnMouseUp` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.onmouseup(v=VS.100).aspx) similar to the way shown above. I also like to provide a public `DeselectAll` method for convenience that both calls the `ClearSelection` method and sets the `CurrentCell` property to `Nothing`.

(Code samples are all arbitrarily in VB.NET because the question doesn't specify a language—apologies if this is not your native dialect.)

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, I got it working but my datagridview didn't have a `=HitTestInfo.Nowhere` i had to change it to..... `If myDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y) Is myDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y) Then`... works as intended, but not 100% sure why it works. First HitTest code implemented.

Comment: @nora The code you wrote doesn't really make any sense. It should not have worked. The [`Is` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx) compares the types of two reference variables. So all you're doing there is checking that the `HitTest` property returns a value of the same type as the...`HitTest` property. It's like saying `If True = True`.

Comment: @nora (continued)  In reality, the [`HitTest` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest.aspx) returns a value of type `HitTestInfo`. [`HitTestInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittestinfo.aspx) is a non-inheritable class that contains, among other things, a static field named `Nowhere`. This is the field that you need to compare against. I suppose what's tripping you up is that the `HitTestInfo` class is a *nested* class of `DataGridView`. I've updated my answer to explicitly qualify it.

Comment: I was thinking about this before, are there not perhaps two 'HitTests', one for the Blank Space, and One for the Cells occupied space?.. So the HitTest above is saying `If Blank Space Is Blank Space Then`.. Where the cell version would be something like `If Cell Space Is Cell Space Then`.. maybe?.. just wondering why mine works with a `True = True` situation ? If I click a Cell the highlight stays, if i click a blank space it goes away.

Comment: Do not call ClearSelection too soon!

Comment: @TaW That comment would be more helpful if you specified what you meant by "too soon".

Comment: Well, I found that e.g. after filling a DGV in the constructor __is__ 'too soon'. Moving the ClearSelection to Form_Shown works fine.. Not sure what the exact rule is; maybe something like 'after layout'? I added the note as there are many comments on similar post that find ClearSelection doesn't work for them. So adding it to theis high-voted answer seemd like a good idea.

Comment: Sorry to revisit an old thread but I ran into the same problems as @nora and, just for the benefit of future visitors, I think there's a syntactic issue with the code provided by Cody. You can't use `If myDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y) = DataGridView.HitTestInfo.Nowhere Then` because : Operator '=' is not defined for types 'DataGridView.HitTestInfo' - I believe this line should be written thus : `If myDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).Type = DataGridViewHitTestType.None Then` (basically a VB version of tinmac's C# version below...)

Answer (score 10):

C# version:

```
if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dgv_track.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.None)
            {
                dgv_track.ClearSelection();
                dgv_track.CurrentCell = null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

i found out why my first row was default selected and found out how to not select it by default.

By default my datagridview was the object with the first tab-stop on my windows form. Making the tab stop first on another object (maybe disabling tabstop for the datagrid at all will work to) disabled selecting the first row

Comment: This actually solved my problem too. For some strange reason changing the `TabStop` property to `false` seems to load the form without a selected `DataGridView` cell/index.

Comment: This doesn't work. If you set a breakpoint on the SelectionChanged event and enable .NET Framework Source Stepping, you can see a call from OnHandleCreated() to MakeFirstDisplayedCellCurrentCell(). This is why it happens, not because it can be "tabbed" into.

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
dgv.CurrentCell = null;
```

when user clicks on a blank part of the dgv.

Answer (score 0):

i have ran into the same problem and found a solution (not totally by myself, but there is the internet for)

```
Color blue  = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CCFFFF");
Color red = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFCCFF");
Color letters = Color.Black;

foreach (DataGridViewRow r in datagridIncome.Rows)
{
    if (r.Cells[5].Value.ToString().Contains("1")) { 
        r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = blue;
        r.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = blue;
        r.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = letters;
    }
    else { 
        r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = red;
        r.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = red;
        r.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = letters;
    }
}
```

This is a small trick, the only way you can see a row is selected, is by the very first column (not column[0], but the one therefore). When you click another row, you will not see the blue selection anymore, only the arrow indicates which row have selected. As you understand, I use rowSelection in my gridview.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.net use for the Sub:

```
    Private Sub dgv_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles dgv.MouseUp
    ' deselezionare se click su vuoto
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        ' Check the HitTest information for this click location
        If Equals(dgv.HitTest(e.X, e.Y), DataGridView.HitTestInfo.Nowhere) Then
            dgv.ClearSelection()
            dgv.CurrentCell = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

gridView1.ClearSelection();

gridView1.FocusedColumn = null;

use thishope this will work in your condition