# How to deselect rows on ASP.NET GridView control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

How can I deselect all selected rows in ASP.NET GridView control when the user clicks on a blank part of the control? For a similar question at [How to deselect all selected rows in a DataGridView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314673/how-to-deselect-all-selected-rows-in-a-datagridview-control) Cody Gray explains so well how this can be done in DataGridView, But what I need is to implement Cody's solution for a GridView control, preferably using vb.net. Thanks

Comment: There answer was written here:

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662413/how-to-unselect-all-rows-in-gridview-asp-net

Comment: I have seen that already. All I want is to have that event done by a click on a blank part of the control, Just the way it is done with datagridview as Cody explains. Thx

Comment: oh so, basically the only difference will be on using a GridView instead of a DataGridVIew?

Comment: Yeah... basically that's the point

Answer (score 1):

First of all `asp:GridView` will be having *utmost only one `SelectedRow`* at any given instance. Secondly, one cannot *Select* or *DeSelect* a row using JavaScript as the Select event is a ServerSide event and not a ClientSide event.

---

However, there is a workaround for this by forcing a server side click using JavaScript. Pseudo code.

Markup

```
<asp:Button ID="demobutton" runat="server" 
    OnClick="demobutton_Click" style="display:none" />
```

Code-behind

C#

```
protected void DemoGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //TO DO: make script a global variable
        var script = "document.getElementByID('" + demobutton.ClientID + "').click();";
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
    }
}
protected void demobutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DemoGrid.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

VB.NET

```
Protected Sub DemoGrid_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        'TO DO: make script a global variable
        Dim script = "document.getElementByID('" & demobutton.ClientID & "').click();"
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", script)
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub demobutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    DemoGrid.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub
```

P.S: I did not understand your **when the user clicks on a blank part of the control**, so I have set it to the whole row.

Comment: I mean to click anywhere on the page to have the row deselected. The issue is that a detailsview is shown by selection of a row. I already created a button which deselects on click by 'GridView.SelectedIndex = -1' in the code behind file which then hides the detailsview. The button click works fine, but I find it unnecessary on the page, if I can just click anywhere on the page to have the rows deselected, and then having the detailsview hidden. Could you also please translate that code to vb.net. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a following gridview

```
<asp:gridview runat=server id=gridview1>
</asp:gridview>
```

Selected row in the gridview will have some kind of class with style of selection, for example tr will have a class '.SelectedRow'

Now With jQuery, you can remove this class from all selected rows or all rows with following jQuery code.

```
$("body").not("#<%=this.gridview1.clientid%>").click(function(){
    $("#<%=this.gridview1.clientid%> tr").removeClass("SelectedRow");

});
```

This will unselect every selected row.

Comment: I need to be convinced first that this can not be done by VB.NET or ASP.NET, then  I can learn to use jquery. Thx